# Returns a Parent Element that Matches the Text Inside It?

Tags: jquery, regex, dom

I have a regex which will match the string 'test', but I want it to return the parent element of the text, for example:

```
<div class="foo">test</div>
<div class="other">other</div>
```

and it returns the `$(".foo")` so I can manipulate it.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will search all divs and return those that have text inside matching your_regex.

```
$('div').filter(function () {
  return $(this).text().match(your_regex);
}).whatever_function_you_need();
```

Answer (score 1):

if im understand it you want to get `<div class="foo">test</div>` your do you only want `test`?

i gife u a example off both:

first one:

```
$('.foo').parent(); or $('.foo').parent().html();
```

if you only want the text `test` you can do :

```
$('.foo').html();
```

if im getting it wrong let me know

Comment: I think Warrantica wants to retrieve $('.foo') via a function so he can use it. This answer is using $('.foo') which the users does not have yet.